# Mac OS X = UNIX?

Tags: macos, mac, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Unix is Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/49434/how-unix-is-mac-os-x)

People always said ubuntu, linux is UNIX based OS, then how about mac os x?
from mac os x terminal i can see most of the unix command are available does it mean mac os also built on UNIX?

Comment: What do you expect from an answer?

Comment: Duplicate of "How Unix is Mac OS X?" at http://superuser.com/questions/49434/how-unix-is-mac-os-x

Answer (score 15):

Yes.

[Indeed 10.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) and [10.6 are Unix (tm) certified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) which linux is not.

To be more specific, Mac OS X is built on Darwin---a derivative of BSD---running on a Mach microkernel.

Comment: URL/Reference? I know they were busy doing it (Apple being Unix licensee already because of A/UX), didn't know the outcome.

Comment: UNIX 03 certified, indeed. 10.5:
http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3555.htm and 10.6:
http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3581.htm

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X is based on the Berkeley Software Distribution. BSD *is* Unix.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is:

> Mac OS X, whose "X" represents the Roman numeral for "10" and is a prominent part of its 
>   brand identity, is a Unix-based operating system, built on technologies developed at 
>   NeXT >between the second half of the 1980s and Apple's purchase of the company in late 
>   1996. Its sixth release Mac OS X v10.5 "Leopard" gained UNIX 03 certification while running > on Intel processors.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X

As another poster stated it's also Unix certified: http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3555.htm

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X is a genetic UNIX (being a descendant of NEXTSTEP and ultimately BSD, a genetic UNIX).

It's also a UNIX-like OS (being UNIX-like).

See the relationship to UNIX and Linux here:

http://www.netneurotic.de/mac/unix/timeline.html

Note that Linux is UNIX-like but no genetic or trademark UNIX. Mac OS X is both a trademark and a genetic UNIX.